# Realm - Swift store a protocol type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have the following structure:

```
class Entity : Object {
    dynamic var Id = 0
    dynamic var Title = ""
    dynamic var Subtitle = ""
    var atttribute : MyProtocol?
```

}

Is there a way of storing something in attribute?
Today is returning nil. If I add dynamic it returns the error:

```
Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

Is there any way to store properties that conform to a Protocol as that?

Comment: Do you want to do lazy loading  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Realm properties are monomorphic, and Realm needs to know what the concrete object type that will be linked to is at initialization time.

Comment: I see this question today after 5 years and 2 month :) , and I want to know realm properties are still monomorphic?